# Laravel 5 error 500 server error. Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trailing the Apache error log and this is what I have found. I am shipping the laravel app from a repo to Azure.

```
[Mon Aug 27 22:17:27.467036 2018] [php7:error] [pid 1055] [client 73.185.186.39:54779] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/58a8d136f27a8497f537e716a972e6c2ef58a48b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/larave...', 122, Array)\n#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/larave...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)\n#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(128): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put('/var/www/larave...', '<?php $__env->s...')\n#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51): Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/larave...')\n#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\En in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122
[Mon Aug 27 22:17:27.467805 2018] [php7:error] [pid 1055] [client 73.185.186.39:54779] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/58a8d136f27a8497f537e716a972e6c2ef58a48b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/larave...', 122, Array)\n#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/larave...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)\n#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(128): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put('/var/www/larave...', '<?php $__env->s...')\n#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51): Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/larave...')\n#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\En in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122
```

Comment: fix permissions, I suspect you uploaded as root etc.. `chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R`

Comment: Try removing all cache files from bootstrap folder then composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'storage' folder should have write permission. Please check the folder is with write permission